# One kind of ASCII arithmetic gives segmentation fault while another doesn't

Tags: c, math, ascii, cs50

So if I do this, I get segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) 
{
    string word = "WORD";

    for(int i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++) {
        word[i] += 32;
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
}
```

whereas if you do this:

```
        printf("%c", word[i] + 32);
```

it works as intended. What gives?

Comment: Where did `string` come from?  `string` is not a valid keyword in C.

Comment: Assuming `string` is a `typedef` for `char*` ... `word` points to a *read-only* place of memory (containing `"WORD"`). Trying to change the contents of that space invokes Undefined Behaviour (segmentation fault in your specific case).

Comment: From cs50.h. I don't think that's the problem though.

Comment: The abomination of a header file has done more to get beginning C students off on the **wrong** foot over the last decade than has the lowest of the low in  academia instructors. It is hideous, completely unnecessary, and should never have been used for a single course, much less for the years its been around.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I agree that such a technique is not for beginners.  By the time you're *not* a beginner, you probably don't need it.

Comment: `word[i] += 32;`?  Just no.  Use `tolower()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is not a standard C symbol, and is likely defined in your `cs50.h` header file as:

```
typedef char* string;
```

This means that variable `word` is a reference to ***constant*** data, data that cannot be changed.   So when you try to do the line:

```
word[i] += 32;
```

You are trying to change data that cannot be written to, hence, seg-fault.

Comment: To be clear, `char*` is not the problem.  `"WORD"` is.

Comment: So as I understand char *, on the other hand, will not refer to constant data?

Comment: I like to label literal strings as *read-only* rather than **constant** to avoid issues with the `const` keyword. String literals are not `const` objects, they're `/*read-only*/` objects :-)

Comment: @ILoveYeezis: `"WORD"` is the constant data that your `char*` variable is pointing to.  If you had malloc'd that memory, the outcome would have been different.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So strictly speaking, string wasn't the issue. Alright, thanks.

Comment: @pmg: I think you're thinking of a different programming language. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey [C11 6.4.5p6: ... For character string literals, the array elements have type char ...](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) ... note type `char`, not `const char`

Comment: "data that cannot be changed" --> Maybe it can, maybe not, maybe program crash.  Better described as UB "The program attempts to modify a string literal" C17 J 2.

Comment: @pmg: Do you have another reference for `read only`?

Comment: `/*read-only*/` is personal preference, not standardese

Comment: `string` is defined in `cs50.h` as `typedef char *string;`, not as a macro. The statement in the answer “This means that variable `word` is a reference to constant data” is incorrect; it is not “this” (the definition of `string`) that means `word` is a reference to constant data.